# Let $K$ be a finite normal extension of a field $F$. Prove that for every $\alpha \in K$, the norm of $\alpha$ over $F$ is in $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Let $K$ be a finite normal extension of a field $F$. Prove that for every $\alpha \in K$, the norm of $\alpha$ over $F$, given by $$\prod_{\sigma \in G(K/F)}\sigma(\alpha)$$
>   is an element of $F$.

I know the norm of $\alpha$ is fixed by G(K/F), but having no idea how to show $\alpha \in F$. Could you please give me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the finite field extension $K/F$ we claim that the norm of $\alpha$ is given by $\det (m_{\alpha})\in F$, where $m_{\alpha}: K \rightarrow K$ is the $F$-linear map of multiplication by $\alpha$. The proof that this equals $\prod_{\sigma \in G(K/F)}\sigma(\alpha)$ is standard for algebraic number theory, see for example K. Conrad's [article](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/154Page/handouts/normtrace.pdf): However, most of the time it is also assumed in the beginning that the extension is *separable*. Then we can of course say immediately that $\alpha$ is fixed by the Galois group $G=G(K/F)$ of $K/F$ and hence $\alpha\in K^G=F$.

Comment: To add on the last sentence : Let $c \in K, c \not \in F$. Then $K$ is a finite extension of $F(c)$. View it as an algebra over $F(c)$ and extend naturally $\rho \in Gal(F(c)/F)$ to $\rho \in Gal(K/F)$. Then $Gal(F(c)/F)$ is non-trivial because $F(c) \simeq F[x]/(p)$ where $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $c$, having more than one root since $K/F$ and hence $F(c)/F$ is separable.